# Influxdb issue telegraf [inputs.exec] Error in plugin: metric parse error: expected tag at 1:2: "7"

Tags: bash, tomcat, influxdb, telegraf

I have an issue when writing to the influxdb from telegraf input exec. I am getting this error  `[inputs.exec] Error in plugin: metric parse error: expected tag at 1:2: "7"`

When I run the bash file, it gives the correct output below to be able to write to the influxdb, The output from bash file is

```
7
7
{"eol":"2021-03-31"
2021-03-31"
2021-03-31
2021-03-31
2022-12-31
-640
tomcat_endoflife,url=https://endoflife.date/api/tomcat/7.json,expiry=2021-03-31 indicator=2
```

The script I used is below :

```
 #!/bin/bash
  
tomcat version | grep -i "Server.*number" | sed 's/Server.*number:*//' | cut -d. -f1 | xargs
 signversion=`tomcat version | grep -i "Server.*number" | sed 's/Server.*number:*//'  | cut -d. -f1 | xargs`
  echo "${signversion}"
 curl -s "https://endoflife.date/api/tomcat/"${signversion}".json" | grep -i "eol"   | cut -d. -f1 | cut -d, -f1
 curl -s "https://endoflife.date/api/tomcat/"${signversion}".json" | grep -i "eol"   | cut -d. -f1 | cut -d, -f1 | sed 's/^.\{8\}//'
curl -s "https://endoflife.date/api/tomcat/"${signversion}".json" | grep -i "eol"   | cut -d. -f1 | cut -d, -f1 | sed 's/^.\{8\}//'  | sed 's/.\{1\}$//'
  varexp=`curl -s "https://endoflife.date/api/tomcat/"${signversion}".json" | grep -i "eol"   | cut -d. -f1 | cut -d, -f1 | sed 's/^.\{8\}//'  | sed 's/.\{1\}$//'`
  echo "${varexp}"
datefuture=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
echo "${datefuture}"
 let math=(`date +%s -d "${varexp}"`-`date +%s -d "${datefuture}"`)/86400
 echo $math
varyear=365
varmonth=31

if [ "$math" -gt "$varyear" ]; then
   #echo "It is greater"
    indicator=0
 
    elif  [ "$math" -gt "$varmonth" -a "$math" -lt "$varyear" ]; then # greater than or less than
    indicator=1

#echo "greater than or less than"
elif [ "$math" -le "$varmonth" ]; then #less than or equal to

#echo "It is less than a month and expire"
      indicator=2

fi

 echo tomcat_endoflife,url=https://endoflife.date/api/tomcat/"${signversion}".json,expiry="${varexp}" indicator="${indicator}"
```

The conf file from telegraf is :

terminal command : telegraf -config  test_api.conf -test

```
[[inputs.exec]]
  commands = ["bash /xxxx/telegraf.d/api_test.sh"]
   data_format = "influx"
  
  timeout = "30s"
  interval = "5m"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved I supposed to comment out the code that produce this values below :

```
7
7
{"eol":"2021-03-31"
2021-03-31"
2021-03-31
2021-03-31
2022-12-31
-640
```